# Ubuntu 22.04 various problems with second monitor

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have an ASUS ROG STRIX with AMD Ryzen9, Nvidia Geforce RTX 4060, kernel 6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1. I connect to a second monitor via HDMI every morning, befor turning on the computer. I connect it before turning on because I noticed that if I do it after choosing the OS (I have a dual boot with Windows) sometimes Ubuntu does not find the second monitor. 
I have some problems that I think may be related to the second monitor.

1. Every time I need to leave my desk, I lock the screen. Sometimes, when I come back I find the screen turned on on the lock page; other times, I find it turned off and I nedd to press enter to wake it up, but it does not always work: it stays black and there is nothing I can do...I tried to enter password even whit the screen off, I tried to disconnect the HDMI cable, I tried to close the lid and reopen it. Sometimes after a while, one of those things work, sometimes the only solution is to force a shutdown by long-pressing the power button. This problem happens both on Ubuntu and on Windows, and used to happen on Windows even before I had the dual boot
2. Sometimes, even if I specified that if I close the lid I want the pc to suspend, this does not happen...the second screen turns black for a while, but then turns on again and it is unlocked. If I re-open the lid, then the lock-screen is shown. Sometimes, this thing happens even if I don't close the lid but choose "Suspend" from the power-off menu
3. This mornig, I left my desk and locked the screen. When I came back screen was black and I couldn't find a solution to turn it on so I forced a shutdown using the power button. When I turned it on again, the second monitor worked, and the pc monitor started flickering, then a half became completely gray while the other half continued flickering more and more, and eventually turned completely black. I disconnected the second monitor, and the pc monitor started working again. One more detail: after turning on the pc, the flickering started only after logging in.
   **UPDATE:**
   I tried to connect to a different monitor and at first it worked, but the pc monitor had a diferent resolution...I wanted to apply a smaller resolution, but if I change it the pc screen flickers. Actual resolution is 2560x1440(16:9) and it is the only one working...I wanted to set it to 1920x1080

All these problems happen only sometimes (I would say 30-40% of the times...which is a lot, but I wanted to underline that it is not always). I know I haven't given you any command output, but that's only because I don't know what output may be useful...so please, feel free to ask for more details and I will happily add them here.
Thanks in advance for your help and patience.